# Mutate function rounds values down, why?

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, dbplyr

I took database from [this](https://datacarpentry.org/R-ecology-lesson/05-r-and-databases.html) lesson and tried to perform some manipulations with it. Here is my code:

```
install.packages(c("dbplyr", "RSQLite"))
dir.create("data_raw", showWarnings = FALSE)
download.file(url = "https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/2292171",
              destfile = "data_raw/portal_mammals.sqlite", mode = "wb")
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
mammals <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "data_raw/portal_mammals.sqlite")
test <- tbl(mammals, "surveys")%>%
        select(record_id, month)%>%
        mutate(ratio=record_id/month)
test
```

I can`t understand why "ratio" variable is rounded down. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just rounding in printing?  Is `mammals` a data.frame and `test` a tibble? the print method for tibbles tries to be a little more "user-friendly" than that for data frames and often prints to fewer significant digits.  Of course, if you'd actually *shown* us the rounding, we could offer more concrete suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the columns you are taking the ratio of, `record_id` and `month`, are  type integer. This means the answer is being returned in type integer, so it rounds down/discards the decimal places.

No, this is not the default R behaviour. But it is the default database behaviour. Why does this matter? When using dbplyr, the calculations are not done in R but are translated from R to SQL and executed in the database.

The fix is straightforward: start the calculation with the decimal `1.0`:

```r
test <- tbl(mammals, "surveys")%>%
        select(record_id, month)%>%
        mutate(ratio = 1.0 * record_id / month)
```

This works because `1` and `1.0` are different to the database. `1` is a integer type and `1.0` is decimal type. Because the calculation of ratio now starts with a decimal it should now return a decimal.